# How to restore an Angular component after destroy it with the previous state

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs, local-storage, state

My Angular component starts to laod some custom configuration via HTTP calls, and it takes a while for X reason. Then I switch the tab, and this components **becomes destroyed**.

So, when I come back to the previous tab I want to restore my component with the same state that before, without having to wait again to load the same custom configuration, just to display it as before directly.

Which is the best way to manage this workflow? **I imagine that the solution should be something like save the state with RxJs** but I am nos sure about this, and I don't know which operators to use in this case.

So any idea about this?

Comment: Sounds like a use case for [route reuse strategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is a global local storage, and [NGRX](https://ngrx.io/) is there for that with its `Effect` solution.

Otherwise, you can do the call in the parent component ans store in it, but it can be quickly annoying to maintain.

Or, you can keep in memory data cache from call. Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@garfunkel61/https-medium-com-garfunkel61-angular-data-provider-services-in-memory-data-cache-c495a0ac35da).

Comment: Yes, but the thing is not about store the data that the http calls retrieve, because the component has to load some configuration with this data after retrieve it and takes some time. The thing is about store the status of the component after render this configuration. And then, if I destroy it, be able to restore it instantly

Comment: I have added a [solution](https://medium.com/@garfunkel61/https-medium-com-garfunkel61-angular-data-provider-services-in-memory-data-cache-c495a0ac35da)

Comment: I will take a look on this for the moment, thanks you